# Unable to log into Azure SQL database in Azure Portal using AAD Global Admin (member type) account

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am Global Administrator of the Azure subscription I own.

Steps:

- I logged into Azure Portal using my credentials.
- I created an Azure SQL database (including initiating a new Azure SQL Server instance).
- I set the database security to permit both SQL Login and AAD Auth.
- I set my AAD account to be SQL Admin of the server.

In the poral, when I navigate to the 'Query editor (preview)' page for the created database, the option to login via Azure Directory Authentication, displays the following error for my account:

```
    *Login failed for user '\<token-identified principal\>'.*
```

What could the issue be / how can I resolve?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: To troubleshoot, try from an InPrivate/Incognito window, and verify that AAD auth works from another client, like SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio.

Comment: Thanks David. Unable  to logon from Azure Data Tools or via Incognito browser (Chrome & Edge). Error message the same whether from client access or within browser

Comment: “ I set my AAD account to be SQL Admin of the server.” do you mean AAD Admin?  That’s different from the SQL Admin.

Comment: As a member of global administration in  AAD (member type / not guest type), I set SQL admin on the sql server; and I set this to be my AAD account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I created a Group (called is SQLAdmin) in Azure Active Directory; and added my account to this.

I set the SQL Server Admin in the SQL server's Settings\Active Directory page to the SQLAdmin group.

When navigated back to the Query editor (preview) page for the database, the error no longer appeared; and selecting the 'Continue as ....' button provided me access to the SQL Query window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update your credentials on Azure Active Directory? maybe this could help to solve the problem. For example, change your password and try again if doesn't resolve the problem, delete the account and create a new one.

Comment: Thanks Wilmer. I had seen posts regarding a solution being to update credentials. Had not tried this or the option to delete my account and re-create. What I have just tried is to create a new AAD user account (member type / Not guest) - which I set to be Global Admin. 

I logged in to the Portal, using Chrome, as that user and accessed the portal in an incognito window.

I get the same error.